iOS blocks passing session data within an iframe
I have this project with a parent page on one domain that includes an iframe on another domain.
Within this iframe I want to pass session data. This means:
index.php is called within an iframe and session data is set
request.php is called with XHR within the same iframe and same domain
Now, on iOS, request.php does not get the session variables even though the entire thing is contained within that iframe.
Is there a way to configure session variables to be passed.
It works on any other machine and it works if the parent domain is the same as the iframes domain. It seems to be an iOS specific thing.
I have tried different configurations of header settings, session settings, cookie settings like:
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: EXAMPLE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM EXAMPLE");
header("Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' EXAMPLE");


and
session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' => 0, // Session cookie
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => EXAMPLE, // Replace with your domain
    'secure' => true, // Only send cookie over HTTPS
    'httponly' => true, // Prevent JavaScript access to cookies
    'samesite' => 'None' // Allow cross-site cookie
]);

